# Django rest serializer validation errors during update

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a separate serializer for updating a user's account, and for some reason whenever I try to use an invalid input its not sending the validation errors as a response, its only sending back the original values that were set. Eg. old username is abc123, if I try to update it to abc123* i want it to throw an error saying its not a proper format but instead it just sends back abc123 as serializer.data. Anybody know why this is happening?

serializer

```
class UpdateAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
    full_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username', 'full_name']

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if Account.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("This username is taken."))
        if not re.fullmatch(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', username):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("Usernames must be alphanumeric, and can only include _ as special characters."))
        return username

    def validate_full_name(self, full_name):
        if not re.fullmatch(r'^[a-zA-Z ]+$', full_name):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("Invalid name."))
        return full_name

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.full_name = validated_data.get(
            'full_name', instance.full_name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

view

```
class UpdateAccountView(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        account = Account.objects.filter(id=pk)
        if account.exists():
            account = account[0]
            if request.user == account:
                serializer = UpdateAccountSerializer(
                    account, data=request.data, partial=True)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

If you're wondering why I'm using separate serializers for registration and updates, its because these fields should be the only ones users are allowed to update freely.

My best guess is its because of these lines (below), but I can't find a fix.

```
instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
instance.full_name = validated_data.get('full_name', instance.full_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your possible solution is to `raise-exception`. change this lines

```py
 if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

to

```py
 if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
```

And also don't need to overwrite update method in serializer.

In `validated_data.get('username', instance.username)` line we are doing from validate_data dictionary object get username if its not present then set this value which is instance.username. Btw one more thing patch request you should response with status code 200-ok not 201-created.